# Repeat widget n time in Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am getting n as integer number from API. Then based on this n I need to add widget n number of times in Row. I am not getting correct way to implement this. 
I am adding screenshot to explain what I need to achieve with this.

[image]

That rupee icons I need to repeat number of times in Row.

Comment: Simply use `for` loop - `Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) Icon(Icons.directions_run)
        ],
      ),`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a method.

```
List<Text> _myWidget(int count) {
  return List.generate(count, (i) => Text("*")).toList(); // replace * with your rupee or use Icon instead
}
```

Use it in `Row` for instance like this.

```
Row(children: _myWidget(10));
```

Comment: I am getting error saying "A value of type 'List<Image>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Widget'"

Comment: Yes, because the above code is returning you a `List<Widget>`, where are you using `_myWidget`, can you post the code, I showed you how to use in `Row`

Comment: Found the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **for loop** in middle of Widget tree!

```
child: Row(
      children: [
        // add a widget n times
        for (int z=0;z<n;z++)
           YourWidget(),
      ])
```